# Am I missing an implicit conversion here?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have made a simple class which represents a point on the Cartesian plane - the Position class, which isn't working properly. As I increment the decimal coordinates, the integer coordinates don't seem to respond. That is what the `ConsolidatePosition()` method is for. It seems that any Double type numbers that are passed to the `MoveRelative()` method are converted to an integer before being stored in a `*PosPrecise`, as if they had already been processed by `Convert.ToInt32()` (the conversion seems to follow the 'round x.5 to nearest even' rule).

My code uses literal arguments, if that makes a difference. eg. `MoveRelative(0, 0.5)` appears in the code.

```
public class Position{
public int XPos;
public int YPos;
public double XPosPrecise;
public double YPosPrecise;

public class Position{
    public int XPos;
    public int YPos;
    public double XPosPrecise;
    public double YPosPrecise;

    public Position(){
        XPosPrecise = 0;
        YPosPrecise = 0;
        ConsolidatePosition();
    }

    public Position(double x, double y){
        XPosPrecise = x;
        YPosPrecise = y;
        ConsolidatePosition();
    }

    public void MoveRelative(double x, double y){
        XPosPrecise += x;
        YPosPrecise += y;
        ConsolidatePosition();
    }

    public void MoveAbsolute(double x, double y){
        XPosPrecise = x;
        YPosPrecise = y;
        ConsolidatePosition();
    }

    private void ConsolidatePosition(){
        XPos = Convert.ToInt32(XPosPrecise);
        YPos = Convert.ToInt32(YPosPrecise);
    }
}
```

And here are some calls to the code. They are the only calls made for one instance of the class. They are called every 'frame' of my program. I have tested the `Move()` method with whole and near-whole numbers, and the phantom rounding still occurs. As it stands, the output doesn't change after many calls of `Move()`.

```
public void RotateRight(){
    // apply central positioning
    switch(ActorDirection){
        case 0:
            ActorPosition.MoveRelative(-2, 1);
            break;
        case 1:
            ActorPosition.MoveRelative(2, -2);
            break;
        case 2:
            ActorPosition.MoveRelative(-1, 2);
            break;
        case 3:
            ActorPosition.MoveRelative(1, -1);
            break;
    }
    ActorSprite.RotateRight(true);
    ActorDirection = (ActorDirection + 1) % 4;
}

public void Move(int direction){
    while(ActorDirection != direction){
        RotateRight();
    }
    switch (ActorDirection % 4){
    case 0:
        ActorPosition.MoveRelative(0, -0.5);
        break;
    case 1:
        ActorPosition.MoveRelative(0.5, 0);
        break;
    case 2:
        ActorPosition.MoveRelative(0, 0.5);
        break;
    case 3:
        ActorPosition.MoveRelative(-0.5, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

My question is, am I missing an implicit conversion here?

(This is written and compiled in C#)

Comment: Post the calling code, along with the expected and actual output.

Comment: Demonstrate the failure as code, rather than by description. This code as is does not have any errors. It would depend how you are using it.

Comment: It's a little complicated, I have kind of rigged the console to behave like a display for a cute ansi-art spaceship. I have tested the program with integer input, and it works as expected. Perhaps 2 files is too much code to post? I will try to give it some context.

Comment: @bimmo when asking questions (anywhere, not just in SO) you can help everyone out by reducing the problem set as much as possible. Try to find/write the smallest amount of code required to reproduce the problem before pasting code. Very often doing so will also yield the answer for yourself.

Comment: So the numbers are broken before you call ConsolidatePosition? Its hard to tell what the question is.

Comment: LordTakkera, Well, it appears so. Every time I call `MoveRelative(0, 0.5)` and then do it again, the *Pos variables remain at 0. It is as if the `0.5` is being rounded as it is passed to `*PosPrecise`, assuming the consolidation doesn't do it.

Comment: Make unit tests and test your `Position` class. This has the advantage that single methods can tested in a isolated way without embedding them in a complicated application. Also the tests can easily be repeated after you make changes to the class. See [Create and run unit tests](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/create-and-run-unit-tests-vs.aspx).

Comment: I have made a basic tester. I can't recreate the error. I will have another look at my other code. Perhaps the rest of the code is messing with the Position. It's just frustrating. I will have a look at your link.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the rounding of the decimal values when converted to integers is causing the problem here (as in it's a usage problem). (double)0.99 converts to (int)0. Perhaps you're looking for Math.Round()?

Comment: but that's what `*PosPrecise` is for - to maintain accuracy even if the integer coordinates are used. I've tried to recreate the error unsuccessfully. Perhaps there is something manipulating the instance of the Position class somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

SORRY ALL. The problem was that a screen-wrap function returns a new position object with integer precision, not decimal precision. This was being called every game step, and replaced the old Position object, never allowing the *PosPrecise to reach more than 0.5. When the function result was set to my object, it reset to 0. It wasn't an error in any of the above code, and Payo was correct, it was how I was using it.